# Como armazenar dados de Cartões de Crédito de forma segura?

Tags: segurança, armazenamento, cartão-de-crédito

Atualmente uso serviços de terceiros para poder lidar com transações online via cartão de crédito, eles mesmos armazenam os dados do cartão e fazem a cobrança.

Estou querendo armazenar os dados do cartão de crédito dos clientes no meu próprio banco de dados, ter esses dados comigo possibilita migrar de serviço sem perder esses dados de cartão, só que isso não me parece seguro, pois se fosse não usaria criptografia para senhas. Como armazenar dados de cartão de crédito de forma segura?

Answer (score 4):

Se você não precisa desses dados rotineiramente, somente terá que acessá-los em circunstâncias excepcionais, então é possível armazená-los de forma segura utilizando criptografia. O ideal, é claro, seria evitar esse problema, ou deixar que algum especialista o faça (em particular, tenha atenção a qualquer legislação vigente que estabeleça critérios mínimos de segurança para esse cenário, se aplicável). Mas para referência, o procedimento seria o seguinte:

1. Gere, em um computador não conectado à internet, um par de chaves público/privado. Mantenha esse computador fora da internet, e livre de malware (ou ao menos retire a chave privada dele, e apague-a do seu local de origem sem deixar rastros);
2. Exporte a chave pública para seu servidor web;
3. No seu serviço web, quando você receber um cartão e precisar armazená-lo, criptografe-o usando a chave pública e armazene o resultado no banco (continue descartando os dados em formato plano tão logo não precisar mais deles);
4. Quando/se eventualmente você precisar desses dados de cartões para migrar um serviço ou coisa assim:

   1. Exporte seu banco de dados para um arquivo, e insira esses dados no computador que possui a chave privada;
   2. Lá, decripte os dados e prepare o script necessário para utilizá-los;
   3. Mova o script para uma máquina com acesso à internet, execute-o e apague-o imediatamente (de novo, usando um método seguro de remoção, que não deixe rastros).

Bônus: use um módulo de hardware para gerar esse par de chaves, de modo que a chave privada não saia nunca desse hardware (i.e. nenhum atacante remoto terá acesso a ela, ainda que 100% do seu sistema esteja comprometido), e uma vez que a chave pública tiver sido exportada *desplugue* esse módulo e não o use mais enquanto não tiver necessidade.

Fonte: [essa resposta no security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/53045/6939). (Nota: não dê atenção à minha própria resposta lá...)

Answer (score 0):

Segundo um [exemplo da própria microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124632(v=sql.100).aspx) (não sei se é o melhor exemplo para citar rsrs). Eles simplesmente não guardam a senha, mas guardam os outros dados do cartão sem criptografia, se baseando que terão um banco de dados seguro o suficiente. Você pode também criptografar esses dados antes de inseri-los do banco, isso vai servir como segurança extra.

Se os dados estiverem criptografados, alguém que tenha acesso ao banco de dados porém não possa ver o código fonte da sua aplicação, não conseguirá decifrar os dados que tiverem acesso.

Comment: Na parte `Eles simplesmente não guardam a senha` não seria o código de segurança? A senha nem é usada na internet.