# Armazenamento de dados de cartão de crédito no banco de dados

Tags: segurança, pagamento-online

Estou prestes a incorporar um módulo de pagamento em meu aplicativo mobile (Pretendo usar o Moip e futuramente o PagSeguro). Eu gostaria de um sistema de pagamento estilo Uber, no qual o cliente fornece os dados de seu cartão de crédito e estes ficam salvos para que posteriormente ele possa pagar com apenas um clique.

Meu conhecimento em segurança de dados é praticamente nulo, e eu gostaria de saber quais precauções devo tomar na hora de armazenar estes dados em meu banco de dados.

Projetei o sistema para não armazenar o código CVV para melhorar a segurança. Mas não acho que isso seja suficiente. Alguém poderia me dar akgumas dicas ou, se possível, me indicar algum material o qual eu posso estudar para desenvolver este módulo de pagamentos "in-app"? Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Contratar um especialista. Meu conhecimento está bem longe de ser nulo, tenho 35 anos de experiência com TI e em segurança eu prefiro contratar um especialista. Eu só tenho medo que mesmo com toda essa experiência vou conseguir contratar um bom. Imagine se eu vou arriscar me virar com algo tão sério. Acho a pergunta muito ampla.

Comment: Reforço o que o @bigown disse. É uma responsabilidade muito grande para arcar sozinho. O ideal seria a contratação de um terceiro para auxiliar com o desenvolvimento. Eu vi em alguns bancos grandes técnicas como não salvar o numero inteiro do cartão (ocultar com **** apenas deixando os primeiros e ultimos 4 salvos), e possivelmente criptografar os demais caracteres em outra tabela (não tive acesso a essa tabela). Mas o ideal seria alguém com experiência fazer isso. Um mínimo descuido pode causar a ruína do seu sistema e da sua reputação lidando com isso.

Comment: Compreendo. Vocês estão inteiramente corretos. Eu sou o único funcionário de uma startup. Ou seja, meu chefe joga tudo em minhas mãos. Nesse caso, eu não posso assumir a responsabilidade, é muito perigoso. Muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há um tempo atrás, antes do *MercadoPago* e do *PagSeguro* estarem populares, trabalhei em uma empresa e eles queriam processar os pagamentos diretamente com a operadora. Na época a operadora disse que não poderiam reter dados do cartão do cliente, e um monte de exigências para poder fazer a integração com o sistema deles. Não sei agora qual a postura, mas de qualquer forma, tem o seguinte link que tem várias referências interessantes quanto a segurança, com as normas **ABNT**, **ISO** e outras como **SOX** a respeito: 
http://mcsesolution.com.br/blog/2016/02/29/padres-e-normas-relacionadas-segurana-da-informao/

Veja por exemplo esse trecho do PCI (Payment Card Industry), que dá sugestões de segurança de armazenamento como *tokerização* e *criptografia*

> A tokenização tem um objetivo semelhante à criptografia, mas funciona
>   de maneira diferente. Ela substitui os dados do cartão por dados sem
>   significado (um “token”), que não têm valor para um hacker.

Fontes: https://pt.pcisecuritystandards.org/minisite/env2/
[https://pt.pcisecuritystandards.org/*onelink*/pcisecurity/en2pt/minisite/en/docs/Small_Merchant_Guide_to_Safe_Payments.pdf](https://pt.pcisecuritystandards.org/_onelink_/pcisecurity/en2pt/minisite/en/docs/Small_Merchant_Guide_to_Safe_Payments.pdf)

Fora tudo isso, tem esse post aqui mesmo do SO sobre o tema, sugiro a leitura: [Como armazenar dados de Cartões de Crédito de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122887/como-armazenar-dados-de-cart%C3%B5es-de-cr%C3%A9dito-de-forma-segura)

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas fontes Ricardo! Cheguei a conclusão de que eu não posso assumir essa responsabilidade visto que não sou um especialista em segurança da informação e sou o único engenheiro/desenvolvedor da startup onde trabalho. De qualquer forma, valeu! Vou estudar as referências e conversar com meu chefe à respeito.

Comment: @BrenoMacena, é uma boa decisão, muita responsabilidade, tem boas empresas que fazem isso, e você sempre vai poder cobrar delas sobre a responsabilidade com a segurança